# symfony security firewall authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication, firewall

I have a knowledge problem I guess.

I thought, secure an area is done by the firewall. So for my understanding, I only have to write the area down inside the "access_control" to secure it by roles, isn't iT?

Actually, my security.yml looks like:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: pbkdf2

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_MODERATOR:   [ROLE_AUTHOR]
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_MODERATOR]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
             pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
             security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            # restrict the firewall to specific http methods
            methods: [GET, POST]
            access_denied_url: /error403
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                # the user is redirected here when they need to log in
                login_path: /login
                # if true, forward the user to the login form instead of redirecting
                use_forward: true
                # login success redirecting options (read further below)
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            /de/dashboard/
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false

                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path: /login
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
                invalidate_session: false
                delete_cookies:
                    a: { path: null, domain: null }
                    b: { path: null, domain: null }

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/administration, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But if I login with a "ROLE_USER" account, I can access the "administration path anyway.

Where is my problem? Do I miss somenthing? Do I need a listener or something or will this be handled automatically?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you need to check the security access in the controller that renders that page using something like:   `if (!$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
}`

Comment: if you try `- { path: ^/administration/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }` or with `- { path: ^/administration/$, role: ROLE_ADMIN }`, to protect the whole administrator path, resolves the issue?

Comment: No, it won't. It's not working. Do I need to setup sth else for get it running?

Comment: I do not use more fosuserbundle, but there are many missing info to try to debug this issue. Check carefully the fosuserbundle docs and also the compatibility with other bundles you could've installed.